# Print a list of One Hot Encoder values

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I`m using sklearn library to encode one column with categorical data to One Hot Encoder values.

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [3])], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
```

Is there a method in sklearn library to print a list of categorical values with assigned One Hot Encoder code?

For example, if I have categorical data "A", "B", "C", I want it to print something like "A" 0 0 1, "B" 0 1 0,"C" 1 0 0, so I can track back which code to which value was assigned.

I tried to use .get_feature_names() method, but it gives me error.

---

Tried this, but it gives AttributeError: 'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names_out'

```
encoder = ct.named_transformers_['encoder']

feature_names = encoder.get_feature_names_out(X[:, 3])
categories = encoder.categories_(X[:, 0:3])

for i, category in enumerate(categories):
    print(category, feature_names[i])
```

Comment: Did you mean [get_feature_names_out()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.get_feature_names_out)?

Comment: No, I tried to use get_feature_names(). Looks like it is deprecated now.